# How can I prevent 3rd party calls from the deverlopment environment without the use of conditional logic?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, production, pinecone

I am currently working on a Python application that stores user data into Pinecone. the problem that I am facing is that I cannot test the code without altering the production database.

The simple solution would be to use something like this:

```
python
is_dev = os.getenv("ENV_MODE") # DEV or PROD
def add_to_vector_database(data):
    if is_dev == "DEV":
        continue
    # do something with the database
    ...
```

However, this solution poses many issues. The first one being that this logic would scale poorly and would have to be pushed into production.

Pinecone does not support local simulators so I cannot create a local version to test it.

Aside from creating a personal index and adding it to the environment variables. Is there a better solution to this? Is it right to push conditional logic like the one above to production?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Read about "mocking" in a unit testing tutorial.